# Mishnah Pesachim 9:7 - Why does the registration of an inherited Paschal Lamb not automatically get assigned to a father's son?

Tags: passover, mishna

**Mishnah Pesachim 9:7 - Why does the registration of an inherited Paschal Lamb not automatically get assigned to a father's son?**

In the [Mishnah Pesachim 9:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.9.7?with=all&lang=bi), we read :

> "With regard to one who separates his Paschal lamb and then dies, his son may not bring it after him for the purpose of a Paschal lamb because it may no longer be used for that purpose after its owner has died." ( הַמַּפְרִישׁ נְקֵבָה לְפִסְחוֹ אוֹ זָכָר בֶּן שְׁתֵּי שָׁנִים, יִרְעֶה עַד שֶׁיִּסְתָּאֵב, וְיִמָּכֵר, וְיִפְּלוּ דָמָיו לִנְדָבָה. הַמַּפְרִישׁ פִּסְחוֹ וָמֵת, לֹא יְבִיאֶנּוּ בְנוֹ אַחֲרָיו לְשֵׁם פֶּסַח, אֶלָּא לְשֵׁם שְׁלָמִים )

[Explanation of the Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.9.7?with=English%20Explanation%20of%20Mishnah&lang=bi)

> The mishnah teaches that even the son who inherits from his father cannot offer it as a pesah. **In other words the son does not inherit his father’s registration for that sacrifice.** Therefore it is sacrificed as a sacrifice of wellbeing.

- Why was this decision established? (Would the desire for registration fees be the cause of this law?)

Comment: What are registration fees?

Comment: Being appointed as part of a karban isn't something that gets inherited.

Comment: והכא מיירי שלא נתמנה בנו עמו כדאיתא בגמרא: Tosfot Yom Tov

Comment: Because at the point the father died no one was counted for the karban thus making it a pasul karban.